# Hoeffding's inequality applicability for sample complexity

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, learning-theory, vc-dimension

I am trying to determine some bounds for sample complexity. Suppose we have a bounded loss function $\ell$ and target function $f:\mathcal{X}\to\mathcal{Y}$. Hypothesis $h$ is learned, then the empirical risk is is the mean of the computed loss:
$$\hat{R}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\ell(h(x_i),y_i).$$
And the true risk is the expected loss:
$$R=\mathbb{E}_{(x,y)\sim P}[\ell(h(x_i),y_i)].$$

I know Hoeffding's inequality holds for a single hypothesis $h\in\mathcal{H}$ and is applicable when you have some bounded loss function $\ell\in[a,b]$. Then, for training set of $n$ size and $\epsilon>0$:
$$P(\vert\hat{R}-R\vert\geq\epsilon)\leq \delta=2e^{-2n^2\epsilon^2/\sum_{i=1}^n(b_i-a_i)^2}.$$

So my question is can I apply Hoeffding's inequality for a general sample complexity bound? My hypothesis space is infinite and I'm working with a multiclass problem with a neural network so I can't just apply VC dimensions. I know Natarajan's dimensions could apply but I'm trying to find something a bit more simple, just to have a relatively simple bound for the training set size. Can I do this or am I making a terrible mistake? I apologize for any misunderstandings in advance, I haven't had a formal class on matters related to PAC learning.